# RTK Query pagination : How to get all cached data of the same endpoint with different arguments

Tags: material-ui, redux-toolkit, formik, rtk-query

Im using RTK Query with [Material UI DatagGrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) to implement a similar use case to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-community-forked-w4u9fo?file=/src/RenderBoolean.tsx).

The data grid is part of a form (with other inputs) that I want to post when the user clicks on a button.

The pagination is handled server-side and and I'm using the [updateQueryData](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#updatequerydata) to update cached data when the user toggles the checkbox of any row in any page.

When the user posts the form, I'm able to get the other inputs values using [formik](https://formik.org/) and then intercept the formik.onSubmit event to append the datagrid rows to the posted data :

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
  service: null,
  zone: null
},
validationSchema: validationSchema,
onSubmit: (values) => {
  values.agents = agents;
  // make http request to post values
},
```

});

I'am actually using a [createSelector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) to compute the `agents` variable :

```
const selectFetchAgentsQueries = (state) => state.api.queries;
export const selectAllSelectedAgentsInAllPages = createSelector(
  selectFetchAgentsQueries,
  (queries) => {
    const queryKeys = Object.keys(queries).filter((queryCacheKey) =>
      queryCacheKey?.startsWith(agentsApi.endpoints.fetchAgents.name)
    );
    return queryKeys.flatMap((queryKey) => {
      queries[queryKey]?.data?.agents;
    });
  }
);
```

Is this is best way to get all cached data of same endpoint but with different arguments (typically page number) ?